# Changing the "Yours" & "Mine" Names in CVS Tortoise Merges

Tags: version-control, merge, cvs, tortoisecvs

I use Tortoise to interact with CVS for source control. When merging it shows you a diff of the files calling the one on your HD "Yours" and the one in the repository "Mine". Or maybe I have that backwards. As you can see that nomenclature confuses me. Then I also have to try to remember which to merge into.

Is there a setting to change that naming scheme? Maybe to "OnHD" and "FinalInRep".

**Update 1**

Mark Davidson, changing yours and mine
as your prescribed

> I haven't tested it but go
>
> 1. TortoiseCVS-Preferences
> 2. Tools Tab
> 3. Two-way merge parameters
>
> in that it currently has set "%mine"
>   "%yours", you might be able to change
>   them to something else, but have not
>   tested it.

Changes the paths my diff tool looks for, not what CVS calls the file. As such, it doesn't change what CVS displays, it breaks my merge tool.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but go

1. TortoiseCVS-Preferences
2. Tools Tab
3. Two-way merge parameters

in that it currently has set "%mine" "%yours", you might be able to change them to something else, but have not tested it.